# Why does my GUI never look right?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, look-and-feel

Built using Netbeans GUI builder on a Mac in Java.

This is what the GUI looks like in Netbeans:

[image: Netbeans GUI]

When I click preview, it doesn't look too bad, but there are small changes:

[image: GUI Preview]

Lastly, when I run it, it looks like this: - terrible

[image: Look and feel]

I assume it's to do with Java's 'Look and Feel'. I've tried removing this and the GUI becomes a shambles. So what are my options? As you can see everything lines up in Netbeans, when I run it, everything is a mess.

Any ideas? Spent a day messing around with this and i'm fed up to say the least

Comment: It look like Netbeans is setting [AQUA](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBLookAndFeels) as it's look and feel but when you run the application the default is being selected.

Comment: It seems so! I see there is no way to change the default GUI builder L&F to Aqua or Nimbus but you can Metal. How can I go about doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some where in you code, Netbeans would have created a `main` method (this will be within the class that Netbeans exeuctes and is probably your master frame - I think that would be the `SPPMainGUI`)

It will look something like this (note that it might be "folded" so you will only see the first comment and the `decs` of the second (`Look and feel setting code (optional)`))

```
/* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
/* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
 * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
 */
try {
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
//</editor-fold>
```

Unfold the code block by click on the little + in the margin and replace the `for-loop` with `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` as below

```
/* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
/* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
 * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
 */
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
//</editor-fold>
```

As afsantos identified the problem, I would appriciate it if you could accept his answer as been correct (and an up-vote me instead ;), nudge, nudge, wink, wink, say no more)

Comment: Ninja'd: yours is a more complete answer, +1

Comment: I have found it and had a play and found that this does nothing but give me a standard UI which breaks a lot of things! Is there a way I can change the GUI builder L&F on a Mac to Metal? As I understand how to change the GUI to Metal when it is run and built now!

Comment: Sure, I'm not sure why, but hay, using `UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName()` instead of `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqUsingMetalLFForPerformance

Found how to change it to Metal in the editor by default too!

Answer (score 5):

From the looks of it, the preview in Netbeans is using a different *Look and Feel* from the one Java is using when you run the application.
However, you may try to manually set the *Look and Feel* you want. There is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) from Oracle, on how to get and set the *Look and Feel*.

Comment: This is definitely the issue, however I cannot find the same one as Netbean's GUI builder so it lays out the same - any ideas?

Comment: @JohnVasiliou afsantos answer is correct and should be marked as such, but I've added an answer outlining what it is you should be looking for

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, it has to do with the Look and Feel, so really, the only issue if finding what L&F Netbeans uses by default. A Google brought up [this page](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/NimbusLookandFeel_OBE2012/CustomizingLandF.html). I quote,

> In NetBeans 7 the default look and feel is automatically set to Nimbus
>   look and feel.

[From Oracle:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html)

> Nimbus is a polished cross-platform look and feel introduced in the
>   Java SE 6 Update 10 (6u10) release.

To enable the Nimbus Look and Feel, simply add these self-explanatory lines somewhere:

```
try {
    for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
}
```